# Bootstrap .carousel(number) not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am having trouble using the `carousel(number)` method to change to an image. My HTML is the following:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="my-carousel-id">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&text=one" alt="" />
               <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Image 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         ...
</div>
```

And to change the image I am using the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
        var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
        var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
        id = parseInt(id);
        console.log(id);
        $('#this-carousel-id').carousel(id);
    });
});
```

The code is working fine until the `.carousel(id)` method is used where nothing happens however the id is passed through correctly. My question is why is this method not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the native bootstrap carousel controls:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#my-carousel-id" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#my-carousel-id" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#my-carousel-id" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

But if you want to use a custom carousel control you need pass the index, [0 based, similar to an array](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

You carousel id is wrong, maybe thats why it didn't worked for you. In your js code you use $('#this-carousel-id') instead of $('#my-carousel-id').

I've created an working example for you on [**jsfiddle, check it out**.](http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ey2/)